# Reference second parameter in function on second iteration of foreach loop

Tags: powershell, foreach, parameters, iteration, ip-address

Here I have two parameters that will take an IP address as input ($ip and $ip2)

```
function createnic () {
    param(
        [string]$vpg = $(throw "vPG name required."),
        [string]$ip = $(throw "IP Address required."),
        [string]$ip2 = $(throw "2nd IP Address required."),
        [string]$prefixlength = $(throw "Prefix Length required.")
    )

    $myvdpg = Get-VDPortgroup -Name $vpg

    foreach ($vm in $vms) {

        New-NetworkAdapter -VM $vm -Portgroup $myvdpg -StartConnected -Type Vmxnet3 -Confirm:$false

        foreach ($srv in $list) {

            $ipdata = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $srv -ScriptBlock { Get-NetIPConfiguration | where { ($_.InterfaceDescription -like "vmxnet3*" -and $_.IPv4Address.IPaddress -like "169.*") } }

            $ipdata = $ipdata.InterfaceIndex

            Invoke-Command - ComputerName $srv -ScriptBlock { New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex $using:ipdata -IPAddress $using:ip -PrefixLength $using:prefixlength }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like the foreach loop to reference $ip2 on the second iteration, and $ip on the first iteration.

Comment: The outer or inner `foreach` loop? Also, where is `$list` defined? :)

Comment: I'm unsure if I got what you mean but if you want to loop over some elements with a foreach you have to provide the elements in the right order to the loop. So I'd think you could create an array by using `$ip, $ip2` ... or did I get it wrong?

Comment: the outer loop, and $list is defined locally on my machine using get-content

Comment: So, what happens the third time? `$ip` should be picked again?

Comment: ah, sorry should have mentioned, the list will always only have 2 items

Answer (score 1):

If you always have exactly 2 items `$vms`, use a regular `for` loop instead:

```
$ips = $ip,$ip2
for($i = 0; $i -lt 2; $i++)
{
  $vm = $vms[$i]
  $ipAddress = $ips[$i]

  foreach ($srv in $list) {
    # ... pass $using:ipAddress to Invoke-Command in here
  }
}
```